# Activating Anaconda Environments on Scientific Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, path, anaconda

I just added python 3.5 to anaconda's environments using `conda create --name py35 python=3.5 anaconda`

I added anaconda's bin, envs and py35's paths to the PATH variable in turn with no effect.

I always get the same error:

```
>>> source activate py35
activate: No such file or directory.
>>> activate py35
Error: activate must be sourced. Run 'source activate envname'
instead of 'activate envname'.

Usage: source activate ENV

adds the 'bin' directory of the environment ENV to the front of PATH.
ENV may either refer to just the name of the environment, or the full
prefix path.
>>> cd anaconda/bin
>>> ls | grep activate 
activate
activate-global-python-argcomplete
deactivate
>>> source activate py35
Illegal variable name.
```

I'm so confused

edit: `echo $PATH` gives

```
/local/home/sread/Apps/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:/local/home/sread/Apps/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/envs:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:/local/home/sread/Apps/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/envs/py3k:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:/local/home/sread/Apps/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/envs:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:/local/home/sread/Apps/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:/local/home/sread/Apps/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:/star/java/jre/bin:/star/java/bin:/soft/cuter:/soft/cuter/CUTEr.large.pc.lnx.gfo/bin:/soft/sifdec:/soft/sifdec/SifDec.large.pc.lnx.gfo/bin:/local/home/sread/Apps/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/local/home/sread/Apps/anaconda/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/soft/bin:/soft/AstroMatic/bin:/star/bin/startcl:/star/bin:/star/starjava/bin
```

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the commands need to be run at the system prompt, not the python prompt (>>>). Try exiting python before running "activate envname" or "source activate envname" if you are on Windows or Linux respectively.

Comment: I was in terminal. Not Python. I just used >>> for some clarity (apparently that backfired)